# Import NumPy gives me ImportError: DDL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

My Environment: Win10 64 bits, Python 3.6 and I use pip install to install NumPy instead of Anaconda. NumPy version: 1.13.0

I have seen several people posted similar questions, but most of them are using Python 2.7. The closest solution I have seen so far is: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1508 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272. But it seems they did not solve it in the end and the people who posted it are using Python 2.7. Therefore, I was wondering if someone can help me about this. My error log is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Kevin>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in 
<module>
from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in 
<module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in 
<module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in 
<module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in 
<module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "D:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in 
<module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be 
found.
```

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272

Comment: @cgohlke Yep I saw that too lol and finally I decided to roll version back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with doing a clean install of numpy. Just don't go with the traditional way but download the wheel file instead. You can get the wheel file from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Download this file- `numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` and install this wheel using pip. Check by importing numpy from shell.

Comment: Yeah I think this is due to some compatibility problems because when I roll the version back, it works fine.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?. If it did can you accept my answer?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to bother with finding the wheel file just uninstall numpy and install an old version:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
pip3 install 'numpy<1.13'
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall NumPy and after that type:

```
pip3 install numpy==1.12
```